# Compenser un achat dispendieux en utilisant le produit à excès

Tags: vocabulaire

J'ai un mot sur le bout de la langue, mais je n'arrive pas à le trouver.

Si je pouvais lui donner une définition, il s'agit d'un verbe décrivant le fait d'utiliser un produit à outrance, ce produit étant dispendieux.

Ainsi, on pourrait dire :

> La licence de ce logiciel a coûté extrêmement cher. C'est pourquoi je l'utilise souvent, afin de la {*Le mot*}.

Comment: In English I'd say "use it to the max" or "milk it like a cow," which might give "l'exploiter au max" or "la presser comme un citron" (but that seems to be only for exploiting people). Regardless, neither of them implies that the initial cost was high. Oh well. It seems that you're essentially [over]using the license this way "to reduce the per-use cost" (sort of like the notion of "economy of scale"), w/the ultimate goal of *recapturing* or *recuperating* its cost, both of which are related to the **amortization** /depreciation of capital expenditures, so, fwLiw, I like @Laure 's 1st answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pour la nuance, je pencherais plutôt pour "Rentabiliser" que pour "amortir".

Rentabiliser fait davantage référence à un grand nombre d'utilisations (si on divise un coût élevé par un grand nombre d'utilisations, alors le coût par utilisation diminue).

Amortir s'utilisera quant à lui pour un investissement, pour quelque chose de planifié. C'est donc plus sur la durée d'utilisation que l'on table. Comme pour l'amortissement d'un gros choc avec un ressort, on divise le coût élevé par une longue durée pour que le coût annuel soit plus faible(indépendamment du nombre d'utilisations).

---

Remarque : "légitimer" pourrait également convenir. Dans ce cas, on sait qu'on a commis une folie en achetant la licence, et on souhaite (se) prouver qu'on avait raison de l'acheter.

Comment: Dans une logique comptable, le terme *amortir* est très courant. On parle généralement d'[*amortissement*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortissement_comptable).

Comment: Je serais d'accord pour préférer rentabiliser à amortir si on se limite à un seul mot. Personnellement, j'aurais plutôt tendance à préférer l'expression "rentrer dans son argent", que l'on emploie souvent au Canada dans de telles circonstances.

Answer (score 6):

Je vois deux possibilités pour exprimer ce que tu décris :

**Amortir** au [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/amortir) :

> Affaiblir graduellement, le cas échéant en la supprimant, une force, une charge pénible.

- > C'est pourquoi je l'utilise souvent, afin d'en **amortir** le coût.
- > C'est pourquoi je l'utilise souvent, afin d'en **amortir** l'achat.

**Rentabiliser** au [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/rentabiliser) :

> Rendre rentable, faire en sorte que soit bénéficiaire une opération financière, une entreprise, une exploitation.

- > C'est pourquoi je l'utilise souvent, afin d'en **rentabiliser** l'achat.